# Spring Security. Разрешить доступ без Аутентификации

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Есть такой конфиг:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
              .antMatchers("/one").hasRole("ADMIN")
              .antMatchers("/two").hasAnyRole("USER", "ADMIN")
            .and()
              .requestCache()
              .requestCache(new NullRequestCache())
            .and()
              .httpBasic();
}
```

Есть endpoint /four.

Что интересно. CURL запрос проходит, а в тестах на запрос к этому url приходит:

```
Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

Как мне настроить конфиг, что бы к нему иметь достуб без всяких аутентификаций (Spring Security)?

Comment: Так пробовали? `.antMatchers("/four").permitAll()`

Comment: @iksuy Full authentication is required to access this resource/. Он разрешает доступ всем авторизированным. А если я данные пользователя вообще не укажу, то не пустет.

Comment: А так `.antMatchers("/four").isAnonymous()`?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev нет(. Я добавил  анатацию WithMockUser() перед сетодом, тогда сработало. Но такое чувство, что не правильно сделал, не разобрался, почему в конфиге и curl можно сделать запрос, а в тестах нет.

Comment: Напишите свой аутентификатор, который будет возвращать пустой UserPrincipal при однотипном запросе

Comment: Если используете `SpringRunner` для ваших тестов, то можно обозначить ваш тестовый класс аннотацией `@WebMvcTest(secure = false)`

Answer (score 0):

````java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Slf4j
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

  @Override
  protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
    return new ScopeAwareMethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
  }

  @Bean
  @Order(0)
  SecurityFilterChain apiResourceSecurityFilterChain(
    HttpSecurity http,
    @Value("${******.issuer-uri}") String issuerHostname
  ) throws Exception {

   
    return http
      .cors()
      .configurationSource(request ->
        new CorsConfiguration()
          .applyPermitDefaultValues()
      )
      .and()
      .antMatcher("/api/**").anonymous().and()
      .build();
  }



}```
````